# How to define the printable area of a react page?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-admin

I render a complex form in the content area of my web application made with react-admin.

The form should be printable without the navigation elements, page header etc. just the content area. The outer container of the content to print looks like this:

```
<div className="printcontainer" id="print_content">
   <LotsOfFancyReactStuff />
</div>
```

This is a react `div` not a html `div`.

Is there a way to define the printable area of the page with CSS or somehow else?

When look at the print preview in chrome now, only the navigation will be printed. The content area will not be printed at all. Since I have a print button on page, a Javascript function or react component for printing would be fine as well. 
Unfortunately I can't just open a popup window and write the content of the container `div` to it due to modern browser security restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Print media query

Add the print media query to your styles. This lets you specify what things should be printable and other specific stylings for your print sheet. Please not browser support.

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 *:not(.print_content) { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Comment: Can I define like "dont print anything, exept #print_content" since all other elements dont have IDs and use several material-ui  classes each?

Comment: you could do use the :not selector. something like *:not(...) should work

Comment: I'll add that part to the answer

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
@media print {
  :not(#print_content > *) {
    display: none !important;
  }

  /* because the first thing does not hide everything */
  .MuiDrawer-root,
  .MuiToolbar-root {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```